# Why am I getting a 'site cannot provide secure connection' ssl protocol error after pushing sign in with google?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I have a next js app using app directory and I'm trying to implement next-auth with google provider.

Here is the code inside my app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.tsx file to initialize next auth, i have removed my client id and secret for the sake of this post.

```
import { NextApiHandler } from 'next';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import prisma from '../../../../prisma/client'


const options = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: '',
      clientSecret: '',
    }),
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

const authHandler: NextApiHandler = (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);


export { authHandler as GET, authHandler as POST };
```

Can someone help me figure out why I'm not being redirected to the sign in with google flow after hitting 'sign in with google' at localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?